# Laravel error for duplicate primary key in cache table

Tags: mysql, laravel, caching

After change my cache drive to database, Laravel started to log the error below. I have thousands of this error now:

> PDOException: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'dbapp_cache_9794540492d50c5a53832f6e31d7ca3fced8f2d2:timer' for key 'cache.PRIMARY' in /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117

I disabled all routes that uses cache, and the error persist. I have no idea what Laravel is caching.

The cache table is full of this timestamps:

[cache table content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj3aN.png)

Any ideias about the sorce of the problem?

**Update:**
After the change of driver, we run this migrations:

```
    Schema::create('cache', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('key')->primary();
        $table->mediumText('value');
        $table->integer('expiration');
    });

    Schema::create('cache_locks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('key')->primary();
        $table->string('owner');
        $table->integer('expiration');
    });

    Schema::table('forms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('user_id');
    });

    Schema::table('respondents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('deleted_at');
    });

    Schema::table('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->index('gateway_id');
    });
```

**Update 2:**
The only place where we use cache is in a Database lock:

```
    return Cache::lock("subscription_{$subId}")->block(10, function() use($request, $subId){
            
       // some code...

    });
```

Comment: Did you run any migrations after changing the cache driver? If yes, please share that.

Comment: @Coola yes, one for create the cache tables another add some index in other tables:

Comment: @Coola I updated the question with the migrations

Comment: As per the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/cache#prerequisites-database the `cache` table should have unique key characteristics and not primary like `$table->string('key')->unique();` Try and see if that helps

Comment: Also how are you accessing / setting the Cache data? Specific lines of code?

Comment: Hey @Coola, I'm sory for the long delay. We are not using cache at all. The only place that's using cache is a database lock. I update the question with this code.

Comment: I just experienced this in my project.  We are also using `CACHE_DRIVER=database` and this error occurs frequently.

If you search the vendor directory (.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/RateLimiter.php), you'll find that the `RateLimiter` class uses `timer` as the cache key.

My wild guess is that if you disabled the throttling middleware, you would not longer see this error message.

Another guess is that if you used a different `CACHE_DRIVER`, you wouldn't see the error and that it'd be considered normal behavior.